# Why (list + 1 2) evaluates to ('(+ 1 2) 1 2) in Common Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Why does evaluating `(list + 1 2)` in Common Lisp (CCL REPL) returns `('(+ 1 2) 1 2)`?

---

More: OK, I see that `+` actually evaluates to the last REPL result, but I still have a question: **Is this a standard CL REPL thing, to have `+` equal to the last result, or is it Clozure specific?**

Comment: The Common Lisp Hyperspec is an excellent reference for the Common Lisp language. It has a reference. Even for non-alphabetic symbols: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Front/X_Alph_9.htm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will find that, in the REPL, the variable `*` holds the last result, and `+` holds the last evaluated form.

For example:

```
> (+ 1 2)
  => 3
> +
  => (+ 1 2)
> (+ 2 3)
  => 5
> *
  => 5
```

Yes, these are standard, and in the [HyperSpec.](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/25_aa.htm)

If you wish to create a list containing the symbol `+`, rather than its value, you will need to quote it, as such: `'+`, or `(quote +)`.

Comment: In addition, `**`, `***`, `++` and `+++` are defined, allowing you to refer to the two values of `*` and `+` that precedes the current one.